# Returning multiple values from embedded Perl script

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script embedded in a C program. I want to return an array of integers from the Perl script. However, the number `n` of integers to be returned, is an input to the program and cannot be hardcoded in the Perl script. Is there a way to do this? Here are a few examples:

Example 1 (n is known and equal to 2 in PERL subroutine):

```perl
@num = {1, 2, 3, 4};
($num[0], $num[1]); // works, returns the two values
```

Example 2 (n is not known):

```perl
@num = {1, 2, 3, 4}; 
(@num); // does not work
```

Example 3 (n is not known):

```perl
@num = {1, 2, 3, 4};
$string = "($num[0], $num[1], $num[2], $num[3])";
$string; // does not work
```

Comment: If it was helpful, please accept sputnick's answer by clicking on the green-white tick to the left from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take care, `{ }` is used for HASH references. I think you simply need :

```
my @num = qw/1 2 3 4/;
@num;
```

or

```
my @num = (1, 2, 3, 4);
@num;
```

or

```
my @num = (1..4);
@num;
```

or usig an ARRAY ref :

```
my $num = [1, 2, 3, 4];
@$num;
```